# Using foldl to count number of true values

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, count

I'm trying to find a way to do the following function with foldl:

```
count a = length (filter (\i -> i) a)
```

It just counts the number of values that are true in a list of booleans. I did try it myself with

```
count = foldl (\i -> 
            case i of
                True -> (1+)
                False -> (0+)
            ) 0
```

Which did not even compile. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your lambda function (\i -> i) is called "id".  So that could be reduced to

count = length . filter id

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So let's check out the types of the functions involved

```
Prelude> :t (\i -> case i of { True -> (1+) ; False -> (0+) })
(\i -> case i of { True -> (1+) ; False -> (0+) }) :: (Num t) => Bool -> t -> t
Prelude> :t foldl
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

So for your list of `Bool`s, b is Bool, but the function you're using has `Bool` as the first argument, not the second. The accumulated value is the first argument. So instead you could do

```
foldl (\acc p -> case p of { True -> acc + 1 ; False -> acc }) 0
```

Or if you'd just like to fix the argument order, use your original function with `flip`

```
Prelude> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c

foldl (flip (\i -> case i of
                           True -> (1+)
                           False -> (0+)
             )) 0
```

Or you can be more succinct: `foldl (flip ((+) . fromEnum)) 0`

Comment: the fromEnum is worth knowing about, but depends on a somewhat arbitrary encoded of  Bool. It would'nt work (in the bad way - it'd compile and run, but we incorrect) if Bool had been wriiten  
data Bool = True | False deriving Enum  
it would be wrong.

Comment: data Bool = False | True was done in that order for a reason ;) It's not arbitrary. It's also defined in the report http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html , so if you do it another way, it's not Haskell anymore.

Comment: Even more succinctly: `sum . (map fromEnum)` – (two passes through the list though, unless you're doing fusion)

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
count = foldl (\i v -> if v then i + 1 else i) 0
```

Another way to do it without `foldl`:

```
count list = sum $ map fromEnum list
```

Credit to Logan for pointing out `fromEnum`. Hadn't heard of that one before.

Comment: Neat. I'm learning Haskell (started a week ago) and the best I could come up with was:


count list = foldl (+) 0 (map (\i -> if i then 1 else 0) list)